# php add <br /> only after first 100 characters

Tags: php

How to add `<br />` only after first 100 characters? I mean just break once, not add `<br />` after each 100 characters.

```
$str="Apple has announced that co-founder, former CEO and chairman of the board Steve Jobs has passed away at the age of 56, so we take a look back at the famous innovator's life.At left, Steve Jobs, chairman of the board of Apple Computer, leans on the new 'Macintosh' personal computer following a shareholder's meeting Jan. 24, 1984, in Cupertino, Calif. The Macintosh was priced at $2,495.";
//echo substr($str, 0, 100).'<br />'; this will break sentence after 100 characters. 
//echo wordwrap($str, 100, "\n<br />\n");this will add <br /> after each 100 characters.
```

And what I need is:

```
Apple has announced that co-founder, former CEO and chairman of the board Steve Jobs has passed away    
<br /> <-- only add here.
at the age of 56, so we take a look back at the famous innovator's life.At left, Steve Jobs, chairman of the board of Apple Computer, leans on the new 'Macintosh' personal computer following a shareholder's meeting Jan. 24, 1984, in Cupertino, Calif. The Macintosh was priced at $2,495.
```

Comment: What charset encoding will the value of `$str` have? UTF-8?

Comment: UTF-8. All the words in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to get the first 100 characters and add a `<br />` then and get all other chars after. Example:

```
<?php
    echo substr( $string , 0, 100)
         , "<br />"
         , substr( $string, 100 );
?>
```

Comment: The answers of [santiagobasulto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679607/php-add-br-only-after-first-100-characters/7679660#7679660) and [MasterCassim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679607/php-add-br-only-after-first-100-characters/7679647#7679647) are helpful, but you should think to not cut the text in the middle of some word. For example if the 100th character is "e" in "Steve", you will cut of the word.

Comment: Hey! That's really similar to my code. Which surprisingly i posted before you! Haha ;) Doesn't matter. It's licenced under GPL. Hope it helps to @cj333

Comment: Yeah, i think yours is better. It's good to include documentation links. I always forget that.

Comment: Regarding documentation, [you should actually look into this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679607/php-add-br-only-after-first-100-characters/7679871#7679871).

Comment: @hakre: Why was the reference deleted from my post? I like to give a link where you can get more information.

Comment: You might not have seen it, I added the link to the PHP manual on substr instead. The examples from w3schools are normally bad compared with the PHP manual.

Comment: @hakre: Yeah, missed it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you meant to write "break up after 100 *letters*" instead of *characters*, then `substr` won't do. And `wordwrap` does work recurringly. So you would need to manually find 100 letters and inject a break there:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.{100,}?\b/s', "$0<br>", $str);
```

Comment: This places the `<br>` at the end of the string, one workaround would be to max at 100 (`{0,100}+`) or to give a range. [I opted for range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679607/php-add-br-only-after-first-100-characters/7679871#7679871).

Comment: @hakre: Oh right. Used the same additional greedines quantifier workaround: `{100,}?` does do.

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a function to insert a string into another at a specific position, it's called [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
echo substr_replace($str, '<br>', 100, 0);
```

If you need to support UTF-8 (you have not specified any encoding), you can do this with a regular expression and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) which allows to not cut words, too:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.{80,120}+\b/su', '$0<br>', $str);
```

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen: I'm not sure that `\b` works as intended for `u` modifier, as `\w` and `\W` don't change. This is a defect with my suggestion. And if no boundary is found at all in that range, there is no fallback.

Comment: `\b` is supposed to work with recent PCRE_VERSIONs. But as workaround `(?=\PL)` might work in place of `\b`.

Comment: @mario: Has that changed for `\w` as well? I always thought they don't wanted to do it because looking up the properties takes it time.

Comment: [pcrepattern(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcrepattern/) says `\b` depends on what `\w` matches. So by implication `\w` should match all Unicode-letters when UTF8/UCP is set. It even does so depending on the locale setting sometimes. But then, some older PCRE versions might have problems.

Comment: @mario In the php manual it's still written that this is excluded from `u`, but as you wrote this might have changed already. Too lazy to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="Apple has announced that co-founder, former CEO and chairman of the board Steve Jobs has passed away at the age of 56, so we take a look back at the famous innovator's life.At left, Steve Jobs, chairman of the board of Apple Computer, leans on the new 'Macintosh' personal computer following a shareholder's meeting Jan. 24, 1984, in Cupertino, Calif. The Macintosh was priced at $2,495.";
$first_part = substr ( $str ,0,100);
$second_part = substr ( $str ,100); //Goes to end of str
$new = $first_part."<br />".$second_part;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
<?
    $str="Apple has announced that co-founder, former CEO and chairman of the board Steve Jobs has passed away at the age of 56, so we take a look back at the famous innovator's life.At left, Steve Jobs, chairman of the board of Apple Computer, leans on the new 'Macintosh' personal computer following a shareholder's meeting Jan. 24, 1984, in Cupertino, Calif. The Macintosh was priced at $2,495.";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i += 99)
    {
        if ((strlen($str) - $i) < 100) {
            echo substr($str, $i, strlen($str));
        } else {
            echo substr($str, $i, 100);
        }

        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
$text = "...";
if (isset($text[100])) {
    $text[100] = $text[100] . "<br />";
}
```